# Is SARIMA(0,0,1)$_\text{s}$ actually MA(s)?

Tags: arima, seasonality

Since for SARIMA(0,0,1)$_\text{s}$ the model equation is $x_t =e_t+a e_{t-s}$, can we say this is a kind of a MA(s) model?

Comment: What do you think about my answer? If it is helpful and clear, you may accept it by clicking on the tick mark to the left. Otherwise, you may ask for further clarification. This is [how Cross Validated works](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 1):

I have some doubts about the notation, i.e. whether SARIMA(0,0,1)$_\text{S}$ should be interpreted as SARIMA with all the nonseasonal lag and differentiation orders set to zero. It would be less less ambiguous to write something like SARIMA(0,0,0)$\times$(0,0,1)$_\text{S}$. But notation aside, it is indeed a restricted MA(S) model where all but the last (S$^{\text{th}}$) lag are set to zero.